# NPM shrinkwrap use local module as dependency

Tags: javascript, npm, dependencies, npm-shrinkwrap

I am currently using `cropper` and have `jquery@latest` in my `package.json`. However, `cropper` requires `jquery` as its own dependency which ends up with two versions of jquery being installed and used. I tried adding this to my `npm-shrinkwrap.json`:

```
"cropper": {
  "version": "2.3.3",
  "from": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cropper/-/cropper-2.3.3.tgz",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cropper/-/cropper-2.3.3.tgz",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": {
      "version": "3.1.0",
      "from": "jquery@latest"
    }
  }
},
```

But all that ended up happening is that I have two identical versions of `jquery` installed.

What I need to do is to get cropper to use the local version of `jquery` in my `package.json` and not its own version of it. The only way I have accomplished this is to manually delete the `node_modules` folder from within `cropper` but this is not a long term solution.

How would I get `cropper` to use my local `jquery`? Or get shrinkwrap to not install `cropper`s `jquery` dependency?